# Creating space between two images

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hi guys i am trying to put my images in the middle of the screen using flex box and then adding some padding between each one. However for some reason the first image overlaps the second image and i am trying to sort it out:

As you can see here i got it to work with fa icons which is perfect: [Link here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/39121/)

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="sidebar-social">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a id="header1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img src="Images/phone1.png">
                    <span id="header1span">Reklambyrå</span>
                    </a>    
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="header1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img src="Images/phone.png">
                        <span id="header1span">Reklambyrå</span>
                        </a>    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.services .get_in {
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar-social li {
      text-align: center;
    width: 15.9%;
    margin-bottom: 3px!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding:0;
        display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  color: #383533;
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.sidebar-social a{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sidebar-social a span{
  color:black;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:5px 0 10px 0;
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:'Josefin Sans';
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-paint-brush { color: #FFC600; }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-phone { color:#FFC600 }
```

However now i want it to get to work with actual pictures, i want the same layout but using my pictures instead of the icons, but when i do it, it overlaps completely , So just simply how can i get there to be padding between each div so i can insert photos instead of icons

Thanks

Comment: simply add this style `img {max-width:100%}`

Comment: Give your images a `max-width: 100%;`

Comment: That works but i still want to get more space between both images

Comment: Not sure how to do that, because every time i use padding or margin it does it for both

Comment: Fixed it , thank u guys lol xxx

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code, I added width 100% to the anchor tag.. you had a width of 16.some % and your image was wider than than the container width and thats you it was overlapping.

```css
.services .get_in {
    margin: 0;
}

.sidebar-social {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-social ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
        display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar-social li {
      text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 3px!important;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding:0;
        display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    //background-image: url('//www.fillmurray.com/500/1200');
}

.sidebar-social i {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  color: #383533;
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top:5px;
}
.sidebar-social a{
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.sidebar-social a span{
  color:black;
  font-size:10px;
  padding:5px 0 10px 0;
  display:block;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:'Josefin Sans';
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-paint-brush { color: #FFC600; }
.sidebar-social a:hover i.fa-phone { color:#FFC600 }
```

```html
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="sidebar-social">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a id="header1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img src="//www.fillmurray.com/200/300">
                    <span id="header1span">Reklambyrå</span>
                    </a>    
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a id="header1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><img src="//www.fillmurray.com/200/300">
                        <span id="header1span">Reklambyrå</span>
                        </a>    
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just edited my comment and sorry for lack of explaination

Comment: That's better. Remember you can improve your answer at any time.